# checkbox ng-false-value as null

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have a an angularjs checkboxes with the following markup:

```
<div class="ml20" ng-repeat="rate in auraInfo.rates">
    <label class="aura-checkbox">
         <input type="checkbox" 
                ng-model="model.checkedRates[$index]" 
                ng-true-value="{{ rate.id }}" 
                ng-false-value="????" />
    </label>
</div>
```

**checkedRates** is an array that gets filled with identifiers when the user is checking the checkboxes. There's also a button that sends these identifiers to the server. If the user check and uncheck the same checkbox **a "false" value is sent to server.**

How can I set a null value (or fully remove the item from the array) when the checkbox is unchecked?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does `ng-false-value="{{ null }}"` not work? If not then you'll probably need to filter the null values from the array in the form submit.

Comment: @Romoku, consider posting your comment as an answer as OP said it is the solution for his problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does `ng-false-value="{{ null }}"` not work? If not then you'll probably need to filter the null values from the array in the form submit.